# Delete string in Toolbar control?

Tags: c, winapi

I'm currently adding Toolbar controls to a Windows application. I noticed going through the documentation ([MSDN Toolbar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760435%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) that there's no message or function to remove strings from a Toolbar control, which seems strange since buttons and images can be removed. It's not exactly essential to have this feature, just wondering if I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else that comes across this problem I solved it by using the `TB_SETBUTTONINFO` message to set button text. This way you don't have to add strings to a Toolbar control's string pool.

```
#define ID_BUTTONCOMMAND 101

//...

TBBUTTONINFO tbButtonInfo;

tbButtonInfo.cbSize     = sizeof( TBBUTTONINFO );
tbButtonInfo.dwMask     = TBIF_TEXT;
tbButtonInfo.pszText    = TEXT( "My Button" );

// HWND handle -- window handle to toolbar control

SendMessage( handle, TB_SETBUTTONINFO, ID_BUTTONCOMMAND, ( LPARAM )&tbButtonInfo );
```